# blakcberry os 7 simulator not loading on my system

Tags: blackberry

I've installed blackberry os 7 simulator (9900,9930,9850).

When I open the simulator, the blackberry loading screen is displayed. But Not loading completley.

Its shows like below image for long time.

> [image]

I deleted *.dmp file which is located on

```
C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry Smartphone Simulators 7.0.0\7.0.0.261 (9900)
```

But problem hasn't been resolved.

Comment: delete and re install the JDE 7.0. It happened with me and that solved my problem

Comment: i uninstall the jde 7.0 and install again. But still the simulator not loading fully. Whats the problem.

Comment: Do you have the JDK properly installed? And the environment variables set properly?

Comment: Error - JVM - BlackBerry 9930 Simulator
---------------------------------------
JVM: could not open D:\BB_Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack7.0.0_7.0.0.21\components\simulator\Java\net_rim_bis_lib.cod

Comment: i think the environment variables maybe wrong. because in my system, already ganymede eclipse is in c:, But now i working in galileo eclipse on d:. I updated the jre 7 on galileo eclipse.  What shoud change on environment variables.

Comment: change the JAVA_HOME and the PATH environments .. I guess this should fix it for you

Comment: sometimes this may be some graphic card issue too.. try to re install the eclipse with new version... if u want the tutorial means i will provide you the link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install BlackBerry Java Plug-in 1.3.0 and it will work.. I am currently working on it. I haven't checked with the older versions of eclipse plugins.

Comment: hi, my system has windows server 2008. my friend system has windows xp. its working on his system.  is it any os problem.?

Comment: no i don't think so. What is the Eclipse plugin version you are using ?

Comment: BlackBerry Java Plug-in 

Version:  1.1.2.201004161203-16

Comment: change to BlackBerry Java Plug-in 1.3.0 and check the same

Comment: Technical requirements

    Eclipse 3.6 Helios
    32-bit Windows® XP or Windows 7 (Note: 64-bit versions require 32-bit Java and Eclipse)
    Monitor with a resolution of 1024 x 768 or higher
    PC with Intel® Pentium® 4 processor or compatible (2.5 GHz or higher, 2 GB RAM, 1.5 GB HD free)
    Java SE Development Kit (JDK) 6, update 14 or later

Comment: I saw above the technical requirements in blackberry page. its require windows xp or window 7.

Comment: hi.. i download bb java blugin 1.3 and install it. when i create new project, BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml gives error.

Comment: Hi. when i open the 9930 simulator. it gives error - Error - JVM - BlackBerry 9930 Simulator
---------------------------------------
JVM: could not open D:\BB_Eclipse1_1\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack7.0.0_7.0.0.21\components\simulator\Java\net_rim_bis_lib.cod

Answer (score 2):

In eclipse,
Go to Blackberry menu > Select **Clean Simulator** option and then run your simulator.. It will delete all dmp files,debug files and set to default setup.

I got the same problem.. but now it works fine for me...
This answer may be helpful to you.