# blakcberry os 7 simulator loading forever

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, windows-7, simulator

I've installed simulator os 7 and its loading forever. (its good with simulator os <= 6)

My problem is just like :
[blakcberry os 7 simulator not loading on my system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292318/blakcberry-os-7-simulator-not-loading-on-my-system)
and the problem looks like not solved yet.

My System:

- Processor: Intel core 2 duo @2GHz
- Ram: 4 GB
- Windows 7 ultimate 32 bit service pack 1, with UAC off
- Java sdk 1.6 update 31
- IDE: eclipse galileo 3.5
- Blackberry plugin 1.1.2

is there any suggestion, step, or something configuration how to solve this

Comment: When you say *forever*, do you mean it's taking a long time, or that it **never** finishes starting up?  BlackBerry simulators are really slow, a 2GHz chip isn't that fast, and I don't believe the fledge.exe executable used by the simulators does a good job of using multiple cores (so 2 isn't any better than 1).  Also, the first time you run a simulator (or the first time after cleaning it), it does take longer.  Anyway, please tell us how many minutes it takes, or if it never finishes loading.

Comment: @nate it never completed loading. i waited 15-30 minutes. i once finished with 9900 but after went to homescreen it's always not responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your versions of Eclipse and the BlackBerry plugin are pretty old, might be worth updating them to see if that makes a difference. Current versions are

- Eclipse: Indigo 3.7
- BB Plugin: 1.5.2

As another commenter has said, your hardware is pretty old as well and the simulator is very resource intensive. To give you an idea of simulator performance here's my spec:

- CPU: Intel i7 2700K (overclocked to 3.4GHz)
- RAM: 16GB
- HDD: 128GB Samsung 830 SSD
- OS: Windows 7 Professional 64 bit
- Eclipse: Indigo 3.7.2 (in eclipse.ini I have the following flag: -Xmx768m)
- BB Plugin: 1.5.2
- BB Simulator: Bold 9930

Running (not debugging) the simulator takes 17 seconds to load.

Comment: I want to develop Blackberry apps on lower version also (os 5) so i use bb plugin 1.1.2 since its forward-compatible with newer BlackBerry Java OS versions

Comment: but i guess i have to try your suggestion. i'll download the latest eclipse and plugin and then download additional blackberry sdk versions. hope it can solve my problem. i'll update this when it is solved.

Comment: Version 1.5.2 of the plugin is compatible with OS5.